# What are the Pros and Cons of Managing Private Keys Directly vs Wallet Extension?

Tags: metamask, security, evm, private-key

I would like to develop an app on an EVM compatible L1, however MetaMask currently does not have it on its list of supported networks. Hence the only alternative I can think off would be to manage private keys directly as follows.

On initial load:

1. Prompt connect wallet
2. Prompt existing `privateKey` input or new key-pair generation and store in `sessionStorage`
3. Prompt `password` input and store `hash(password)` in `localStorage`
4. Encrypt `privateKey` with `password` and store in `localStorage`

On subsequent loads:

1. Prompt `passwordAttempt` input and if `hash(passwordAttempt)` matches `hash(password)` in `localStorage` decrypt `privateKey` and store in `sessionStorage`
2. Retrieve `privateKey` from `sessionStorage` for signing transactions when required.

I'm also looking to develop the frontend in Create React App which to the best of my knowledge is resistant to certain attacks such as XSS. But I'm not sure of other security vulnerabilities of directly managing the private keys in the app, other than the web app being compromised by for example a malicious actor deploying malicious code to a production environment.

Could someone please shed light on the pros and cons of using a browser wallet extension and managing private keys directly in app? Also if such vulnerabilities exist would a native app implementing similar privateKey management solve the shortcomings of its web app counterpart?

Comment: If it's an EVM derivative, I think MetaMask might work just fine if you provide a RPC endpoint for the network. Or?

Comment: The network is EVM compatible, but it isn't listed on chainlist.org so to the best of my knowledge I can't specify an RPC endpoint since I don't have at least 1 mandatory field i.e. the Chain ID

Comment: Ah, right. I wonder why it doesn't have chainId, but you're correct, it's mandatory info - can't add without it. Unsure if it's mandatory for it to be listed somewhere (for example chainlist)

Comment: I don't see why it would be mandatory to register a Chain ID, but I can see the advantages of doing so such as MetaMask compatibility.

Comment: It's mostly useful for replay protection. A transaction is only for that chainId, so it can't be replayed in other networks

Comment: True, but I don't think it's necessary for this network as it has its own internal tx schema that properly identifies a transaction is on the correct network and environment.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/132710/discussion-between-mshakeg-and-lauri-peltonen).

Answer (score 0):

There's an even simpler implementation called Burner Wallets for Ethereum that doesn't even store a password hash: see https://burnerwallet.co/ -- it seems so far that there haven't been any attacks. I wouldn't use just password hashes, as then you are vulnerable to a rainbow attack if localstorage is compromised (and that seems like the whole point of your decryption method). Metamask also stores its keys in the browser storage (different for different browsers, can verify in source code here: https://github.com/MetaMask/metamask-extension), so it's not more secure for that reason (again, varies by exact implementation of your application).

Comment: My understanding is that burnerwallet is an npm package that pretty much implements what I proposed except it stores the private key unencrypted in localStorage which would be less secure than my proposal and would still suffer from the same security vulnerabilities which may not exist using a browser wallet extension. Even if MetaMask does store keys in browser storage it would still be more secure as I would imagine it being more difficult to deploy malicious code changes to MetaMask in the Chrome Web Store than to a small startups frontend that would compromise keys.

Comment: Also rainbow table attacks can easily be mitigated by storing a random salt in localStorage that's hashed along with the password.

Comment: Yup -- if you salt your passwords, your implementation should be secure; there's thousands of burner wallet accounts with hundreds to thousands of dollars each, so one would imagine any easy hack on localstorage already would have been exploited -- I'm trying to say that burner wallet's current security means that you are likely fine.

Comment: Fair enough, but since I'm not looking to build on Ethereum burnerwallet wouldn't work well, so I might as well build my own implementation suited to that network. Also using burnerwallet directly is still susceptible to malicious code changes being deployed to production, so unless there's a way to cache an entire frontend(FE) in browser and only allow manual FE updates that clears storage and requires the user to re-enter and trust the updated FE with their keys I don't see how this potential vulnerability can be avoided.

Comment: Right, a re-implementation for your network sounds best. Well, a user always has to trust that the website owner is not maliciously stealing their keys; if you have your own implementation it sounds like you dont have to rely on a third party.

Comment: So I guess another alternative would be to develop native applications that don't refetch the frontend every time the app is opened which gives the user the option to download a new version of the frontend at their discretion, but having a dedicated wallet for signing transactions will always be better as major updates are infrequent.